# Angular2 how to change url using form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm having some issues with my app. I wanted to implement a new functionality - add a form, where you input username and password and then send it to change url. My app takes JSONS from url and JSON content depends on the username and password. The pattern is: `somewebsite.com/username/password`.

**Component**

```
import { Component, enableProdMode, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { VehicleService } from './vehicle.service';
import { User } from './user';

enableProdMode();

@Component({
  selector: 'vehicle-json',
  templateUrl: './vehicle.html',
  providers: [VehicleService]
})
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {
  public vehicles: GeneralVehicle[];
  public user: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService) {
    this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
      this.vehicles = vehicle;
    });
  }

  onSubmit({ username, password }: { username: User, password: User }) {
    console.log("test");
  }
}

interface GeneralVehicle {
  status: number;
  dallases: Vehicle[];
}

interface Vehicle {
  vehicle_id: number;
  dallassettings: string;
  dallasupdated: string;
  dallas_list: DallasList[];
}

interface DallasList {
  number: number;
  auth: number;
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { User } from './user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {
    //used predefined username and password to check if my connection to the website is fine
    private defusername = 'defaultUSERNAME'
    private defpassword = 'defaultPASSWORD'
    private url = 'mywebsite.com/' + this.defusername + '/' + this.defpassword;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getVehicle() {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user)" [formGroup]="user">
    <label>Username:
        <input formControlName="username" type="text" placeholder="Your username">
    </label>
    <label>Password:
        <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

<div *ngIf="vehicles">
    <b>Status: {{vehicles?.status}}</b>
    <div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles.dallases">
        <ul>
            <li>Vehicle ID: {{vehicle.vehicle_id}}</li>
            <li>Dallas settings: {{vehicle.dallassettings}}</li>
            <li>Dallas updated: {{vehicle.dallasupdated}}</li>
            <li>Dallas list:</li>
            <div *ngFor="let d of vehicle.dallas_list">
                <ul>
                    <li>Number: {{d.number}}</li>
                    <li>Auth: {{d.auth}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to implement that functionality. When I edited onSubmit method and added: `console.log(username);` it returned 'undefined' no matter if I filled the inputs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `OnSubmit()` function in the **Component** to get `username`/`password` from the formGroup value:

```
onSubmit(user) {

    // console.log(user.value.username);    // <-- To test username
    // console.log(user.value.password);    // <-- To test password

    this.vehicleService
        .getVehicle(user.value.username, user.value.password)
        .subscribe(vehicles => {

        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    });
}
```

Modify the `getVehicle()` method in Service to use `username` & `password` for generating dynamic URL:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { User } from './user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {
    //used predefined username and password to check if my connection to the website is fine
    private defUsername = 'defaultUSERNAME'
    private defPassword = 'defaultPASSWORD'
    private defUrl = 'mywebsite.com/' + this.defusername + '/' + this.defpassword;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getVehicle(username?: string, password?: string) {

        const url = (!username || !password) ? defUrl : 'mywebsite.com/' + username + '/' + password;

        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

With the above changes, your new feature should start working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Santanu, there's one error in component: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. at: '26,5'`. It seems changing `getVehicle` method interrupts the component's consctructor.

Comment: Hi @Haseoh... Forgot to add the types for getVehicles method parameters. Have made the correction in *Service* (see code above). It should be `getVehicle(username?: string, password?: string) { ... }`. Note the question marks for making the parameters optional because you are calling this method without any parameters in constructor of the component.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it seems so easy, yet i wasted whole day trying to get it by my own - I'm new to this technology.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)